# SQLAlchemy - Classical map relations

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am struggling a bit with SQLAlchemy classical mapping. My scenario is the following one:

```
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.id = uuid.uuid4()
       .....

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.manager = None
```

What I want to do is to convince SQLAlchemy to create a relationship between Client and Manager (where a client has a manager) whiteout having to define a manager id attribute at client level. In the code above 'manager' attribute would be an instance of Manager class. I am using classical mapping in this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
mapper(Client, self._table, column_prefix='_', properties={'managed_by_relation':relationship(User, order_by=self._table.c.id, foreign_keys=[self._table.c.manager_id]))
```

The above code describes what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

seems like maybe you're looking for some way to automate creation of the ForeignKey?   I wrote a blog post about one possible approach to simulating the more "traditional" declarative ORM here: [magic, a "new" orm](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/05/17/magic-a-new-orm/)

Comment: Thanks Mike, much appreciated. I will take a look at it today. Hopefully if I'll be back with more questions you won't mind :).